# Storage location of SharePoint site pages?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-page

I wanted to know if it is possible to change to storage location of newly created site-pages?

So for example:

If I create a new page from a template, I want it to be saved into a specific document library?

Answer (score 0):

With the out of the box feature you cannot do it, however, with the help of Power Automate Flow we can achieve it. Let's say Page library where at present You are creating a page while you save it; you want this page to be saved in a different location, i.e., in a different document library. Before developing the Power Automate flow, you need to add the "Page" content type to your "**Document Library**", Once this is done, Create an automated cloud flow that should trigger on the source "**Page**" library, and add an action to move your created page to your destination "Document" library. Here, if you want to copy two versions of the page, both in the "Page" library and the "**Document**" library, You can maintain or delete your source page from the "Page" library and delete it once it is moved to the "Document" library. All these things can be handled using the Power Automate flow.

You can refer to this [article](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint/scheduled-cloud-flow-move-old-documents-in-sharepoint-automatically/), how does the move file work in Power Automate?